# Getting strange Exception from menu

Tags: android, exception, android-menu, stack-overflow

I am testing my app on some devices varying different android versions.
I tested on my MotoG with KitKat and it runs perfectly but when tested against Samsung with Ice Cream Sandwich, it gives some strange exception.

Here's my `OnCreateOptionMenu()` method:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    menu.clear();//Exception occurs here

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_contact, menu);

    item  = menu.findItem(R.id.addContact);

    //if 5 contacts are already Selected,hide add icon from ActionBar
    if(!contactsList.isEmpty())
    {
        if(contactsList.size() >= 5)
        {
            item.setVisible(false);
            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

    }

}
```

These are some of the LogCat exceptions I got:

```
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176): at java.util.HashMap.clear(HashMap.java:666)
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.BaseMenuWrapper.internalClear(BaseMenuWrapper.java:76)
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176):    at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuWrapperICS.clear(MenuWrapperICS.java:108)
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176):    at com.ContactsFragment.onCreateOptionsMenu(ContactsFragment.java:443)
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateOptionsMenu(Fragment.java:1582)
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentManager.java:1967)
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:225)
10-14 11:47:14.326: E/AndroidRuntime(17176):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:232)
```

Comment: is this happening only when if(contactsList.size() >= 5) is ture?

Comment: Please add the point in your code where it fails ...

Comment: yes, you are absolutely correct @Techfist

Comment: this is your problem, supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() this will call onCreateOptionsMenu() again, and hence forth the stacking of method calls, unfortunetly ending up in stackoverflow execption.

Comment: if my list size is greater than 5 I need to hide some menu item,then how should I do this???? @Techfist

Comment: dont call invalidare from api itself, suppose when user selects conatcts and when it reaches more then 5 in selcetion, then from there call invalidateOptionMenu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call supportInvalidateOptionsMenu() in your onCreateOptionsMenu.....

> After the system calls onCreateOptionsMenu(), it retains an instance
>   of the Menu you populate and will not call onCreateOptionsMenu() again
>   unless the menu is invalidated for some reason. However, you should
>   use onCreateOptionsMenu() only to create the initial menu state and
>   not to make changes during the activity lifecycle.
>
> If you want to modify the options menu based on events that occur
>   during the activity lifecycle, you can do so in the
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu() method. This method passes you the Menu object
>   as it currently exists so you can modify it, such as add, remove, or
>   disable items. (Fragments also provide an onPrepareOptionsMenu()
>   callback.)

I guess it's described above how you should implement it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

// Just use this

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    menu.clear();//Exception occurs here

    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_contact, menu);

            item  = menu.findItem(R.id.addContact);

    //if 5 contacts are already Selected,hide add icon from ActionBar
    if(!contactsList.isEmpty())
    {
        if(contactsList.size() >= 5)
        {
            item.setVisible(false);
        }

    }

}


@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    item  = menu.findItem(R.id.addContact);

    //if 5 contacts are already Selected,hide add icon from ActionBar
    if(!contactsList.isEmpty())
    {
        if(contactsList.size() >= 5)
        {
            item.setVisible(false);
        }

    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Now whenever your list reaches more then 5 contacts capacity call, `invalidateOptionMenu` this will make sure prepare is called and your menu remain hidden in that case.